# Como fazer loop para enviar meus emails?

Tags: loop, phpmailer, email, mailer

Estou tentando fazer o código pegar os emails que vou por em uma lista .txt ou em um form (enquanto não monto o banco de dados) e fazer um loop para enviar todos os emails. Acontece que estou recebendo esta mensagem de erro e não sei como solucionar o problema.

```
<?PHP

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$nm = $_GET['nome'];
$sb = $_GET['sobrenome'];

$address = "andre.lc@msn.com";
$address = "andreleal.cc@gmail.com";

for($loop=0; $loop<4; $loop++){

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $body = file_get_contents('a.html');


  $mail->AddReplyTo("contato@testedeemail.com","EREA SSA");
  $mail->SetFrom('contato@testedeemail.com', 'EREA SSA');


  // Nome e Sobrenome pegos através do GET "site.com/email.php?nome=André&sobrenome=Leal"
  $mail->AddAddress($address[$loop], utf8_decode("$nm[$loop] $sb[$loop]"));
  $mail->Subject = "Teste !";
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);

  //$mail->AddAttachment(""); // Arquivos para anexo

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
  } else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada !";
  }
  $mail->clearAllRecipients(); // Limpa o campo de para quem o email será enviado e o nome

}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bom, a solução já foi encontrada, logo a baixo deixo a solução do problema para quem quiser usar para estudar.

```
<?PHP

require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$nm = $_GET['nome'];
$sb = $_GET['sobrenome'];

$address[] = "teste01@teste.com";
$address[] = "teste02@teste.com";
$address[] = "teste03@teste.com";
$address[] = "teste04@teste.com";

foreach($address as $addr){

  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $body = file_get_contents('a.html');

  $mail->AddReplyTo("contato@teste.com","Opa Epa");
  $mail->SetFrom('contato@teste.com', 'Opa Epa');

  $mail->AddAddress($addr, utf8_decode("$nm[$loop] $sb[$loop]"));
  $mail->Subject = "Teste !";
  $mail->MsgHTML($body);

  //$mail->AddAttachment(""); // Arquivos para anexo

  if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Erro: " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br/>";
  } else {
    echo "Mensagem enviada !<br/>";
  }
  $mail->clearAllRecipients(); // Limpa o campo de para quem o email será enviado e o nome

}

?>
```